# Dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: dual-boot

I have partitioned my hard drive the way required to deal with Ubuntu, and I was wondering :

Every Website I've come across says that GRUB will overwrite the windows boot-loader, so to uninstall Ubuntu you need special software.

Is there any way to install it so that all I have to uninstall Ubuntu is delete the partition, and not have to mess with my MBR???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possibilities to do this.

1. First would be to install Ubuntu using [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide). Wubi installs ubuntu in a single file which acts as a partition.
2. The other way would be to install Ubuntu on a ext4 partition and then install the boot on the partition instead of the MBR and then follow instruction on this [link](http://bkpavan.wordpress.com/2008/04/02/how-to-boot-linux-using-windows-bootloader-xp/). I would recommend [ext3fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) instead of Ext2 IFS for the previous link as the former seems more recent and and better support for ext4. Installing the FS driver would allow windows to access the partition to boot it and then edit boot.ini to add linux partition to it.

Comment: perfect answer, this should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "boot-loader." For example, it will not interfere with a Windows 7 boot partition: only the MBR in all cases. And it is not difficult to rewrite the MBR. To do this I almost always boot from an XP disc into the [Recovery Console](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=314058) and then just `fixmbr`, which does the same job (writes a new MBR) as the older "fdisk /mbr" from Windows 98. Cheesy but easy! Yes?